# sl4j simple logging for scala singleton

Tags: scala, logging, singleton

I am trying to implement sl4j simple logging 
for/inside of a Scala singleton, but it doesn't seem
to be working.

for example, if attempt this, the code will run, but
there is no logging to be had:

```
class Driver{
  Foo.showLogs()
}

import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

object Foo {
  protected val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass.getName)
  showLogs() {
    val lst = (1,2,3,4,5)
    for(l <- lst) {
      log.info("List item :"  + l )
    }   
  }
}
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible ?  Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should log. If it doesn't, it's due to your logging configuration.

1. Do you have an [SLF4J binding](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#projectDep) on the classpath, e.g. Logback or SLF4J-Simple?
2. If you don't, you should see a warning message about the absence of a binding.
3. If you do, it is configured not to show `INFO` logs for `Foo$` (that will be the name of your logger here).

Side note: `log.info("List item :"  + l )` is bad practice. Use either `log.info("List item :{}", l)` or `log.info("List item :$l")` with a Scala wrapper library such as https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging.